# Testing: disconnect TLS connection

Tags: ssl, mobile, wireshark, disconnect

I have a mobile application which connects via TLS to a back end. I would like to test if the connection is re-established timely by the mobile application if the existing TLS connection is disconnected. How to that? I can see the TLS connection in my WiFi router, but it has no option to kill the connection. Using WireShark I can capture, but as far as I know I have no option to terminate the TLS connection ... MITM software, so far, I did not manage to by pass the "Certificate Pinning" from this mobile app ...